# iPad walkthrough screens have too much whitespace

Tags: ios, ipad, structure, white-space

I am designing a walkthrough right now for a iPad app, but I ran into the issue that the page has too much whitespace. The page will have a large header text, an icon/illustration and a button. There will be no description.

Here is a screenshot of the page:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I don't know how to change the structure to make the page better.

P.S. There can't be an image as the background, only a solid/gradient background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem I'm seeing is that your CTA button is so far away from the icon and headline that they don't seem related. Move the "Get Started" button close to the "Scan bar code" and you should eliminate the "white space" issue. [image]